# Make a template page on MediaWiki which substitutes given arguments to an iframe

Tags: mediawiki, iframe, templates, markup

I'm using the [Iframe](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Iframe) plugin and the following code to embed a video from VK:

```
<div style="float:right; margin: 0px 0px 25px 25px;"><iframe k="vk"
 p="video_ext.php?oid=349530500&id=456239067&hash=4561ee8657098af3&hd=2"
w="640" h="360" allowfullscreen="1" /></div>
```

But I would like to write something like this instead

```
{{VkVideo|video_ext.php?oid=349530500&id=456239067&hash=4561ee8657098af3&hd=2}}
```

What should I write in `Template:VkVideo`? If I write the following code

```
<div style="float:right; margin: 0px 0px 25px 25px;"><iframe k="vk"
 p="{{{1}}}"
w="640" h="360" allowfullscreen="1" /></div>
```

it does not  substitute the argument for some reason. So the HTML of the page where I use the template contains this code:

```
<div style="float:right; margin: 0px 0px 25px 25px;"><iframe id="Iframe1"
data-src="https://vk.com/{{{1}}}"
data-delay="50" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extension tags do not take template arguments as they are expected to output HTML which needs to be shielded from template processing. Try

```
<div style="float:right; margin: 0px 0px 25px 25px;">{{#tag:iframe||k=vk|p={{{1}}}|w=640|h=|360|allowfullscreen=1}}</div>
```

(see [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Miscellaneous))

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Another problem was that the url contained the `=` symbols. So I had to invoke the template like this:
`{{VkVideo|1=video_ext.php?oid=349530500&id=456239067&hash=4561ee8657098af3&hd=2}}`